# Are there any settings within hibernate/spring jpa to cope with connection failure and reconnection with Hibernate and Spring JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a web app which uses Spring JPA and hibernate to connect to a mysql database. If the connection to the database were to drop for whatever reason I would like to catch that exception, so that I can pause processing, and then poll that connection forever until it comes back up.

Are there any settings within hibernate/spring jpa to cope with this?

application-context.xml:

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName">
        <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
    </property>
    <property name="url">
        <value>jdbc:mysql:${db.loc}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="username">
        <value>${db.username}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>${db.password}</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.georgelung.template" />
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

TemplateRepository class

```
@Repository
public interface TemplateRepository extends CrudRepository<TestEntity, Long> {

}
```

Comment: Need to post relevant code.

Answer (score 3):

Why to capture connection loss with database and try to reconnect manually when hibernate provide this solution out of box

Add below code in your hibernate configuration should resolve your issue

```
<prop key="hibernate.connection.autoReconnect">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.connection.autoReconnectForPools">true</prop>
```

Comment: The problem with this, is it has a fixed number of retries (default 3) and as @Jordi Castilla points out it doesn't provide the exception handling. Useful nonetheless

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a `getConnection` method like this to ensure you have a valid connection before trying to connect to the DB:

```
private Connection getConnection() {
   Connection connection = null;
   try {
       // This should return a NEW connection!
       Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection(); 
   } catch (Exception e) {
       // here you got the no connection found exception!
       System.err.println("Connection failed: " + e);
   }
   return connection;
}
```

Comment: I think the OP is after settings rather than basic exception catching.

Comment: I suggested this answer because in the question OP says: *If the connection to the database were to drop for whatever reason I would like to catch that exception,* , not actually asking about set up to autoreconnect... what you think @Pureferret?

Comment: Then they go on to say "*Are there any settings within hibernate/spring jpa to cope with this?*"

Comment: Did you see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29769472/1075247)? Should solve the problem.

Comment: yes I did, but after connection fails, and connection can't be reopened... how you provide the feedback to the user? Is this throwing some error or exception or simply getting a super ugly screen provided via framework?

Comment: Why not ask Dev on his question what he expects those settings to show? If you think this is better than his (because it will provide the user with a failure screen) then put that in your question :)

Comment: I don't think mine is better, we answered at same time and share our knowledge, I asked you because you defended the solution and I want to know how it works with this xml configuration  just in order to add to my future apps if necessary to improve them...

Comment: I think it was just the fact that the two answers take completely different approaches, clearly there was a reason you chose this over `hibernate.connection.autoReconnect` setting. Elaborating on this in your answer would be really helpful.